# Query to find elements in particular time interval

Tags: mysql, group-by, hive

I need to find a Hive query that returns the 2 top names for each 6 minutes interval since 00:00:00,

Data looks like -

```
Name    Time
A   00:00:00
B   00:03:53
C   00:01:16
A   00:04:34
A   00:07:32
A   00:18:36
C   00:16:12
C   00:05:04
B   00:01:50
B   00:12:05
A   00:11:20
B   00:04:27
B   00:02:47
A   00:00:23
A   00:00:23
B   00:36:21
B   00:02:46
```

I would like to write the query in Hive which is very new for me but even using mysql query , I can derive the result in Hive.

Comment: In MySQL you would use `GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Time)/360)` to group the rows by 6-minute intervals.

Comment: thanks, but how to get only top 2 elements in each group

Comment: What does "top 2" mean? By alphabet? By count? By time?

Comment: its by time and in the question I mentioned group by with time

Comment: yes I am aware you want to group by time.  but `top 2` is still ambiguous.  top 2 what?  ordered by time?  counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
* 
from
(
select NAME
, time_interval_6
, rank() over (partition by NAME, time_interval_6 order by ct desc) as ranking
from
  (select count(1) as ct
  ,  NAME
  ,  floor((floor(cast(substring(time,1,2) as int)*60 + cast(substring(time,4,2) as int)))/6) as time_interval_6
FROM MY_TABLE
  group by NAME,  floor((floor(cast(substring(time,1,2) as int)*60 + cast(substring(time,4,2) as int)))/6)
   ) a
)b
where ranking <= 2
;
```

Comment: okay one last change.... wrapped in select on outside....  might also want to delete some of the above comments.

Comment: yes .. it worked, it just show all the columns which I can sort out.. Thanks

Comment: As specified by another: You don't have to use substr just specify the format. unix_timestamp(time, 'HH:mm:ss') –

Comment: well then I get values in negative as unix_timestamp expects bigint which time column doesn't